# Directory access forbidden using CI

Tags: php

I am unable to access the directory it display "Directory access forbidden" please help me as I am new in CI

```
<?php     
 if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');  
$config['base_url'] = 'emoneygifts.projects-codingbrains.com/index.php';

?>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? explain please

Comment: $config['base_url'] =  localhost/intranet/CodeIgniter_2.1.4/index.php';

Comment: try to declare like this your project url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> from the documentation https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/index.html
>   in your `application/config/config.php` make setting like this

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/your_project/';
```

> once your done, access your website at :
>   http://localhost/your_project/index.php

**Example:**

```
$config['base_url'] = localhost/Project_name/index.php';
```

**OR**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/project_name/index.php';
```